# Storing public key in web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, key, public

I am trying to store a public key in the web.config file of an ASP.NET website as follows:

```
<add key="public_key" value="<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>zDYX4tbHSyTrwDmjSXiiFTo0ydGK50zxtH2lGL90oWrshMGy16wod7AZMfm8CMd/Rxl3ocIPLTmHSwyBb0xzL6lnF8uJI90s2TBHYemx3tkRQCcW6PZfGBWwlwSzhaNidbibRtoWNImBG4ehzc5Yxg3r6IyUBEtY9xJkL1tIezU=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>"/>
```

This code is located inside the appSettings section of the web.config file.  Unfortunately, it is giving me the following warning along with a number of other errors:

```
Warning 6   The element 'appSettings' has invalid child element 'RSAKeyValue'. List of possible elements expected: 'add, remove, clear'.
```

How can I solve this problem please?  Thank you :)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `... value="&lt;RSAKeyValue&gt;&lt;Modulus ...` ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Marc :)  I appreciate it immensely :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape special characters (`<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`) in this case, because in current state they turn web.config into invalid XML.

Here is the escaped string obtained [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-escape.html):

```
&lt;RSAKeyValue&gt;&lt;Modulus&gt;zDYX4tbHSyTrwDmjSXiiFTo0ydGK50zxtH2lGL90oWrshMGy16wod7AZMfm8CMd/Rxl3ocIPLTmHSwyBb0xzL6lnF8uJI90s2TBHYemx3tkRQCcW6PZfGBWwlwSzhaNidbibRtoWNImBG4ehzc5Yxg3r6IyUBEtY9xJkL1tIezU=&lt;/Modulus&gt;&lt;Exponent&gt;AQAB&lt;/Exponent&gt;&lt;/RSAKeyValue&gt;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Andrei :)  I appreciate it immensely :)